# Android emulator shows nothing but blank screen flashing android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

i am completely noob to android studio and trying my hand on learning android development . i have created emulator using API 22 and it only show blank black screen flashing android as you seen in the picture.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXd5z.png) and i am using linux mint 17.2 os. thank you in advance

Comment: It's still launching. You need to wait a bit.

Comment: check your memory status in task bar

Comment: you should have free memory you have alloted to emulator

Comment: that is called the loading screen. The included emulators are fairly heavy and take quite a while to start.

Comment: You can use Genymotion emulator as well for faster testing.

Comment: wait for a while ,it takes time for processing. sometime it takes more than 40-45 minutes

Comment: sir i tried it but after some times it close itself and show an error                             (emulator-arm: .//tcg/optimize.c:158: tcg_opt_gen_mov: Assertion `temps[src].state != TCG_TEMP_CONST' failed.)

Answer (score -1):

well i wait for almost 1 hour and than after sometime it close itself and show an error (emulator-arm: .//tcg/optimize.c:158: tcg_opt_gen_mov: Assertion `temps[src].state != TCG_TEMP_CONST' failed).                                          sorry for english:P
and last thing i am using linux mint 17.2 os.

Comment: This isn't an answer. You should instead edit your question.